# geopoint query secondary sort by date

Tags: parse-platform

I am querying for objects by a geopoint field : location -

```
var query = new Parse.Query("pointOfinterest");
query.withinKilometers("location", userLocation, searchRadius);
```

I want the primary sorting order to be by distance and secondary by creation date.In other words - I'd like results from the same distance to be ordered by date ( descending - newest first )
so I tried adding :

```
query.ascending("location");
query.addDescending("createdAt");
```

or just:

```
query.descending("createdAt");
```

or :

```
query.addDescending("createdAt");
```

doesn't work - when I add the createdAt , the location order gets messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Parse.com` developer guide:

> Note that if an additional orderByAscending()/orderByDescending()
>   constraint is applied, it will take precedence over the distance
>   ordering.

See this [link](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#geopoints).

So, I think you should get the array first and order it on `createdAt` yourself.

*Also, the order is ascending by distance on default, so no need to order on distance in your query.*

Comment: Thanks. it's obvious I can order it myself, it just seems to me that since parse queries can be ordered by multiple fields, this should be possible in this case.maybe it can't be done( in which case I'll accept your answer )

Comment: I would agree with you completely, but according to the official guide it's not possible for this type of query. See link for more info.